# Get city name either do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels

Tags: sql, oracle

Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

Input Format

The STATION table is described as follows:

```
FIELD    TYPE
ID       NUMBER
CITY     VARCHAR2(21)
STATE    VARCHAR2(2)
LAT_N    NUMBER
LONG_W   NUMBER
```

I write the below query but it does not work. Any suggestion?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CITY) 
FROM STATION  
WHERE NOT regexp_like(lower(CITY),'^[aeiou].*') 
  AND regexp_like(lower(CITY),'.*[aeiou]$');
```

Comment: What about `Y`?

Comment: .....and w?   :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY, '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*[^aeiouAEIOU]$');
```

The regex pattern here matches a whitelist of cities which do not start and do not end with a vowel.  Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
^              from the start of the city name
[^aeiouAEIOU]  match a single non vowel character (lowercase or uppercase)
.*             match any zero or more middle characters
[^aeiouAEIOU]  match another single non vowel character
$              end of the city name
```

Comment: Doesn't match [one-letter place names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_short_place_names), but I think we can live with that :)

Answer (score 0):

try this for ms sql--

```
select distinct city from station where city not like '[aeiou]%' and city NOT like '%[aeiou]'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is My solution in Oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(CITY,0,1)) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. They also need to know if it ends in a vowel. Your answer only checks if it begins with a vowel.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer for this!

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY NOT REGEXP '^[aeiou]'
AND CITY NOT REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL SERVER:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY LIKE '[^aeiouAEIOU]%[^aeiouAEIOU]';
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION

WHERE CITY NOT REGEXP '^[AEIOU]' AND CITY NOT REGEXP '[AEIOU]$';

Here is my answer for this challenge on hackerrank and it worked (SQL server)
Some of my explanations for this:

*REGEXP Syntax: not case sensitive => both lower and uppercase are included.

*'^[AEIOU]': start with vowels

*'[AEIOU]$': end with vowels

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Servers :

`SELECT distinct CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT LIKE '[AEIOU]%';`

Comment: I think you want `NOT LIKE '[AEIOU]%[AEIOU]'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MySQL query to retrieve the city names that do not start with vowels.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE LEFT(CITY,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Comment: Looks to me like you misunderstood the question. It is tagged "oracle" so I don't know if a MySQL query is appropriate. It also requires that the query return cities whose name ends in a vowel as well. I don't see that your query does that.

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'^[^aeiouAEIOU].*[^aeiouAEIOU]$');
```

Comment: This is a verbatim copy of my answer, posted more than a year after I posted.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE( city NOT LIKE 'A%' AND city NOT LIKE 'E%' AND city NOT LIKE 'I%' AND city NOT LIKE 'O%' AND city NOT LIKE 'U%' ) AND ( city NOT LIKE '%a' AND city NOT LIKE '%e' AND city NOT LIKE '%i' AND city NOT LIKE '%o' AND city NOT LIKE '%u') ;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).